# Represent 3 values as 1 in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am attempting to convert a 3 channel numpy array to a single channel numpy array. I want to combine all 3 element values into 1 number using:

> x << 16 + y << 8 + z

My code below does that but it seems to make alot of the numbers zero. Is that correct? Or am I doing something wrong? Should those last 2 numbers be zero or something else?

```
ar = np.array((
    ((255,255,255),),
    ((255,20,255),),
    ((0,255,255),),  # this becomes zero, is that correct? 
    ((22,10,12),),   # this becomes zero, is that correct? 
), dtype='uint8')
c1,c2,c3 = cv2.split(ar)
single = np.int32(c1) << 16 + np.int32(c2) << 8 + np.int32(c3)
print(single)
print(ar.shape)
```

> [[1069547520]
>    [    522240]
>    [         0]
>    [         0]]
>   (4, 1, 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column of zeros to make the array 4 bytes wide:

```
ar4 = np.insert(ar, 0, 0, 2)
```

Then simply view it as a big-endian array of 4-byte integers:

```
ar4.view('>u4')
```

This gives:

```
array([[[16777215]],
       [[16717055]],
       [[   65535]],
       [[ 1444364]]], dtype=uint32)
```

The only step here which really takes time is `np.insert()`, so if you are able to add that extra column while loading your data, the rest of the transformation is basically free (i.e. does not require copying data).